# using foreach to loop but stuck on what to do

Tags: c#

i have a list of collection which returns the following result:

```
GenderID      Name    Gender
1              Mary   F
1              Jane   F
1              Lori   F
2              John   M
2              Mike   M
```

I'm using a foreach to loop through and to create a listview dynamically based on GenderID. I'm stuck as to what to check when the GenderID changes. Can anyone point me out or give me some feedback.

```
public void GetGenderInfo()
{
    int? currentGenderID = null;

    List<Gender> lstGenders = GetListOfGenders();

    foreach (var g in lstGenders)
    {
        currentGenderID = g.GenderID;

        if ( //what goes here )
        {
            // create ListView
        }
    }
}
```

Expected result to be:

```
Mary F     John M
Jane F     Mike M
Lori F
```

Comment: How could a Gender change? (so is gender id for a person in your table) Can you explain a bit more on your expected output?

Comment: @bonCodigo --- this is just an example ... i loop through checking GenderID ... how do i know the last id compare to the current id?

Comment: If your list is offline from db, how could it change in `GetListOfGenders`? It's not static. If `GetListOfGenders` would take a `GetGenderInfo` instance as argument, then you could compare both `Gender` properties with each other(the one passed as parameter and the one in the `foreach`).

Comment: Don't get it do you want to create a listview for each gender, or group by gender???

Comment: @TonyHopkinson -- group by gender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're looking to group by a certian value, you need to keep track of your grouping values. Adding a dictionary of lists takes care of this. Take a look at the code below:

```
public void GetGenderInfo()
{
    List<Gender> lstGenders = GetListOfGenders();

    var tmpDict = new Dictionary<int, List<Gender>();
    foreach (var g in lstGenders)
    {
        List<Gender> currGender;
        if (!tempDict.TryGetValue(g.GenderId, out currGender)
        {
            currGender = new List<Gender>();
            tempDict.Add(g.GendrId, currGender);
        }
        currGender.Add(g);
     }

    //Now itterate your dictionary & pull out the groupings.
    }
```

The `tmpDict` now contains your original list grouped by GenderId.